# What's the difference between Strategy Pattern and IoC

Tags: design-patterns, inversion-of-control, strategy-pattern

In both the Strategy Pattern and in Inversion of Control you can exchange parts of an object that allows scalability and easy-to-exchange parts. I am referring to [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/380748/inversion-of-control-overview-with-examples)

Both use an interface and call the function of the interface.
Am I missing something?

Comment: An Interface is really its own "pattern."  Strategy and IoC both use the "interface pattern."  But that doesn't make them the same pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Inversion of Control** is a means of constructing objects at initialization time.  You design each component of your application to use dependencies, but have something outside the component supply all the requirements.
- **Strategy Pattern** is a means of abstracting away different algorithms, but still consume them in a consistent manner.  There is nothing in a strategy pattern that concerns itself with object construction or selecting the algorithm.

In a manner of speaking, you could argue that Inversion of Control is a specialized application of the Strategy Pattern for object construction.  The Strategy Pattern is a bit more inclusive than that, but the benefit is that you can write your control logic once and have very different behavior based on the implementation of the selected algorithm.